# Missing content length in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest, content-length

I was getting content length properly earlier. Since last couple of days I'm not able to get content length using below code.

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.kite.trade/instruments?api_key=kite_front") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "HEAD";
using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse())
{
    int ContentLength;
    int.TryParse(resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), out ContentLength);
    return ContentLength;
}
```

When I hit same URI with postman I'm getting more response headers including content length.

Anybody can explain reason for same?

Comment: `HEAD` requests aren't supposed to get content.

Comment: @SLaks but response to HEAD request can (and often does) include Content-Length header, even though there is no content in response.

Comment: @Evk  You're right, there might be a `Content-lenght` header. But there's not guarantee that the server will responde to a HEAD request and no promise that, if it does, will contain that header. Sometimes, even if there's the Header, it is set to `-1`. So, this method is quite unreliable.

Comment: @Everyone thanks for your time. Still I'm surprise and it could help me if I get any clue about second method, wheneven I send request from POSTMAN it always returns correct content-length.

Comment: That site, with the URI you posted, responds both to a `HEAD` and `GET` requests, setting the `Content-Lenght` Header to 1112543 (the actual size is higher), `Content-Type` is `text/csv`. It sets a Cookie and requires `TLS 1.2` Server certificate validation => CloudFlare.

Comment: I was wrong. The content lenght is actually correct. Verified after downloading the file.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for you comment. :)

Comment: Do you know how to proceed now (Cookies, TLS validation etc.)?